# Runtime exception when compiling project

Tags: nativescript-angular

When compiling my **Nativescript** project this error occurs.

```
Nativescript: 5.4.2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Class not found android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener
```

How to solve it, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to migrate your application to AndroidX :  [Support for AndroidX in NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/support-for-androidx-in-nativescript)

This tool makes the migration "painless" : [AndroidX Migration tool](https://github.com/NativeScript/androidx-migration-tool)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the **Nativescript** version from 5.4.2 to 6.1.2 and it fixed so many problems. I hope this may help you too.

Comment: This does not provide answer to this question.